# Hibernate NamingStrategy per class

Tags: java, hibernate

The problem is the following. I have an `Embeddable` class (say, `Address`) wuth multiple fields. Abother class (say, `Employee`) has several instance fields of class `Address` (f.e. `homeAddress`, `workAddress`, etc.). Certainly I need to have different column names for `Address` fields in different instances, like `workAddressStreet` and `homeAddressStreet` or something like that.

I can use `AttributeOverride` annotation on each field but this would be very cumbersome. There is an interface [NamingStrategy](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/NamingStrategy.html) that can be used to solve this problem. But as per all docs and samples I could find it can only be used globally, on session level. The the meantime the system I work on has no such stretegies and introducing such would probably change a lot in existing schema. Isn't there a way to apply it only for specific class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really have to use 2 fields like workAddressStreet and homeAddressStreet? 
my suggestion is, just use the addressStreet field and have another field say "addressType" value type = 1 is home, value type = 2 is work.

Comment: Nice idea but I still have several (3 actually) different addresses so I need to map them in some way to different column names in one table.
But your suggestion makes me think of doing `Address` not embeddable and keep them in different table. Hm, maybe this is the way to go...